# What are (Brexit) "Muppet" leaflets?

Tags: word-meaning

I am currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/dutch-port-aims-keep-trucking-despite-brexit-chaos-051304313.html) , and the first passages says,

> The Hague (AFP) - While Boris Johnson scrambled Friday to sell his EU divorce deal to parliament, the Dutch port of Rotterdam handed out **"Brexit Muppet" leaflets** to truckers to prepare them for whatever happens.

[**According to Collins' urban dictionary,**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Muppet) the word "muppet" is

> A person who is ignorant and generally has no idea about anything.

So would the word, Brexit Muppet leaflets, here mean the leaflets for people who don't know anything about Brexit at all?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Muppets](https://muppets.disney.com/) are a group of distinctive-looking, fluffy puppets, notably including Kermit the Frog and Miss Piggy. The term "muppet" can be used to refer to anything that looks like a muppet, even if it's not under that trademark or even a puppet.

Here's one of the leaflets, from [Twitter](https://twitter.com/dannyctkemp/status/1095976399599480832):

[image]

Comment: It might be worth noting that in British casual speech, mainly in London and Southern England, 'muppet' means 'fool'.